# CA and Peer docker containers go down [Hyperledger]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am working with hyperledger composer. I started my fabric using ./startFabric.sh after creating a new peer by adding the details about the same in connection.json and docker-compose.yml. Now, when I try to install my business network archive onto this fabric, i get an error - ECONN refused. On investigating further I saw that the ca.org1.example.com and peer1.org1.example.com docker containers are down. I tried restarting them but agin they go down. Any help here?

[This is what I added to docker-compose.yml to add a new peer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Ur5.png)